# How to convert a Tree in Haskell to a flat list

Tags: list, haskell, tree, list-comprehension, cons

I have a tree defined in Haskell like:

`data NTree a = Nil | Tree a [NTree a] deriving Show`

I want to 'flatten' the tree so that all the nodes appear in a list. I'm trying to do so by:

```
arrayify :: NTree Int -> [Int]

arrayify (x:xs) = x ++ arrayify xs
```

I can kind of tell that this is wrong, but I have no idea how to fix this. For reference, this is the error I'm getting:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘NTree Int -> [Int]’
              with actual type ‘[Int]’
• Possible cause: ‘(++)’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the expression: x ++ arrayify xs
  In an equation for ‘arrayify’: arrayify = x ++ arrayify xs
```

Comment: Where are the `x` and `xs` originate from in the body of the function?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code with the new inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `arrayify` expects an `NTree Int`, you probably want to pattern match on the two data constructors, so:

```
arrayify :: NTree Int -> [Int]
arrayify Empty = …
arrayify (Tree v ts) = …
```

For the `Empty` case, you should return an empty list, for the `Tree v ts` you can make a list that starts with `v` and then has the `arrayify`s of the elements of `ts` as children. You can use the `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` and [**`concatMap :: Foldable f => (a -> [b]) -> f a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) for this.

But instead of writing `arrayify` yourself, you can let Haskell derive an instance of `Foldable` for your `NTree`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data NTree a = Nil | Tree a [NTree a] deriving (Foldable, Show)
```

Then you can call [**`toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList) on an `NTree` object.

Comment: I really like you idea of deriving an Instance of foldable. I tried to do so and then call `toList` on a sample tree. But, I'm getting this: `Variable not in scope: toList :: NTree a0 -> a1
`

Comment: @kashmafia: you import it from `import Data.Foldable(toList)`.